# How to prove a bijection exists between two sets of tuples?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-isomorphism

let $C_{1} = \{a_{11}...a_{i1}\}$ and $C_{2} = \{a_{12}...a_{j2}\}$ also, let  $C'_{1} = \{a'_{11}...a'_{i1}\}$ and $C'_{2} = \{a'_{12}...a'_{j2}\}$. Where $|C_1| = |C'_1| = i$ and $|C_2| = |C'_2| = j$

Now, $\forall (a_{p1},a_{q2}): (a_{p1},a_{q2})\in C_1 \times C_2$, let there be a function $f:C_1 \times C_2 \rightarrow \{l_1,l_2...l_m\} $, where $\{l_1,l_2...l_m\}$ are some labels on each tuple.

Similarly,  $\forall (a'_{p1},a'_{q2}): (a'_{p1},a'_{q2})\in C'_1 \times C'_2$,let there be a function $f':C'_1 \times C'_2 \rightarrow \{l_1,l_2...l_m\} $, where $\{l_1,l_2...l_m\}$ are same labels as in the previous function.

Furthermore, there is exactly the same numbers of tuples labeled  $l_i$ in $C_1 \times C_2$ as there are in $C'_1 \times C'_2$, forall $i \in \{1,..,m\}$.

Now, can we prove that there exists a bijection, B:$C_1 \cup C_2 \rightarrow C'_1 \cup C'_2$   such that $f((B(a_{p1}),B(a_{q2}))) = f((a_{p1},a_{q2})) $ ?

Also, $C_1 \cap C_2= \phi$ and $C'_1 \cap C'_2= \phi$

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: I am immensely confused to be honest. I tried to enumerate tuples in two rows to get some hints but it didnt really give me any idea.

Comment: What is $\lvert C_1 \times C_2 \rvert$? It can't be the size of the product set, can it?

Comment: @loopywalt apologies: error fixed. PS: Please do comment if anything else is not clear. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Unless I grossly misunderstand isn't it easy to constuct counter examples? Choose i=j=m and let f be essentially the projection to the first component and f' essentially the projection to the second  component?

Comment: In your example wont this lead them to have disjoint f and f' mappings ? whereas in the problem it is the same set. As you say that f maps to fist component hence it maps to $C_1$, whereas $f'$ maps to $C'_2$. I hope I got it right.

Comment: Aaah sorry, so this would require $C_1 = C'_2$, which is allowed

Comment: You are welcome. I'm a bit rusty, so I'm happy I didn't talk nonsense ;-)

Comment: I don't think your bijection's domain and codomain are correct

Comment: @loopywalt I am sorry your point was correct but it does not answer the question, as I want to prove that such a bijection can exist. I don't see how in the counter example this would be impossible

Comment: @user20672 Why ? they share the same cardinality.

Comment: Yes the domain of $B$ is union of two disjoin sets and yes the codomain of $B$ is two disjoint sets too. Infact it can be seen that an element of $C_1$ will need to be mapped to an element in $C'_1$. And yes you may construct some trivial bijection but it does not satisfy the condition I mention, furthermore it is still not a bijection between same sets as, the elements of $C'_1,C'_2$ are not the same as of   $C_1,C_2$

Comment: If I understand the setting correctly, then after choosing i=j=m we can identify all five sets with {1,2,...,i} for convenience. Now compare (1,2) and (1,3). No matter what bijection you choose the f and f' from the counter example will map this to the same and to not the same label, contradiction.#

Comment: If $B: C_1 \cup C_2 \rightarrow C_1' \cup C_2'$ and $f: C_1 \times C_2 \rightarrow \{ \ell_1, \dots, \ell_m\}$, then the following expression is not well-defined: $f((B(\cdot), B(\cdot))$. Did you mean $f'$?

Comment: Also $(B(\cdot), B(\cdot)) \in C_1' \cup C_2' \times C_1' \cup C_2'$, but the domain of of $f'$ is $C_1' \times C_2'$. So, again, the expression $f(B(\cdot), B(\cdot))$ is not well-defined for a second reason.

Comment: My first comment of the two immediately above has switched the prime and not prime, but the point is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose two sets $C_1$ and $C_1'$ have the same cardinality. Similarly the two sets $C_2$ and $C_2'$ have the same cardinality. If that cardinality is finite, then we can enumerate each pair of sets with an index set: $I_1 = \left\{1,\dots,m\right\}$ and $I_2 = \left\{1, \dots, n\right\}$. Explicitly these enumerations are provided as:

$$
\begin{aligned}
 C_1  &= \left\{ {}_1c_1, \dots, {}_1c_m \right\} \\
 C_1' &= \left\{ {}_1c_1', \dots, {}_1c_m' \right\}
\end{aligned}
$$

and:

$$
\begin{aligned}
 C_2  &= \left\{ {}_2c_1, \dots, {}_2c_n \right\} \\
 C_2' &= \left\{ {}_2c_1', \dots, {}_2c_n' \right\}
\end{aligned}
$$

Suppose these sets are mutually disjoint. Then the following is a bijection, $B: C_1\cup C_2 \rightarrow C_1'\cup C_2'$:

$$
B(\alpha) = \left\{ \begin{aligned}
B_1(\alpha), & \,\,\alpha \in C_1 \\
B_2(\alpha), & \,\,\alpha \in C_2 \\
\end{aligned}\right.
$$

where we define $B_1: C_1 \rightarrow C_1'$ and $B_2: C_2 \rightarrow C_2'$ as:

$$
B_1({}_1c_j) = {}_1c_j', \quad \forall j \in I_1
$$

and

$$
B_1({}_2c_k) = {}_2c_k', \quad \forall k \in I_2
$$

Let's prove that this is a bijection. First we'll show it's onto. Choose an element $\beta \in C_1' \cup C_2'$. Necessarily, $\beta \in C_1' \oplus \beta \in C_2'$. If $\beta \in C_1'$ then $\beta = {}_1c_j'$ for some $j\in I_2$. We know that ${}_1c_j \in C_1$, and it follows that $B_1({}_1c_j) = {}_1c_j'$. If $\beta \in C_2'$, the same argument can be applied. We conclude $B$ is onto.

Now let's show that it is one-to-one. Suppose there are two elements $\alpha, \gamma \in C_1 \cup C_2$ such that $B(\alpha) = B(\gamma) = \beta$, but $\alpha \neq \gamma$. Then there is a unique ${}_1c_k' \in C_1'$ or ${}_2c_k' \in C_2$ such that $\beta = {}_1c_k'$ or $\beta = {}_2c_k'$. Without loss of generalization we consider the first case, $\beta = {}_1c_k'$ It follows that $\exists {}_1c_j, {}_1c_\ell \in C_1$ such that ${}_1c_j = \alpha$ and ${}_1c_\ell = \beta$. But:

$$
B({}_1c_j) = B({}_1c_\ell) = {}_1c_k' \Longrightarrow j = \ell = k \Longrightarrow \alpha = {}_1c_k = \beta
$$

which is a contradiction. We apply the came argument to the case $\beta \in C_2'$ and conclude that $B$ is one-to-one.

We have shown that $B$ is one-to-one and onto, so by definition, $B$ is a bijection.

---

If you show that $f$ and $f'$ are bijections, then you can show that the statement I *think* you want to prove can be written as the composition of bijections, which is necessarily a bijection. However, as I pointed out in the comments, it seems there are some mistakes in the question statement.

Comment: This cannot be the mapping as $f$ maps to labels and not tuples

Comment: I meant B. Corrected

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but I donnot wish to construct the bijection on the tuples but rather on the sets.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. You want a bijection between unions

Comment: Sorry, my notation sucks a bit I guess

Comment: No, it's fine @SagarM. I just read the question title and gave you a bijection that satisfied the title based on a cursory glance of the question. The fault is mine for not seeing that you actually wanted a bijection between these unions of sets. I'll update this with a more rigorous proof.